# Value of 'firstTime' is always true

Tags: kotlin

Why I am getting error like "value of 'firstTime' is always true"? How to change value to false?

```
fun test(){
        var firstTime = true
        if(firstTime){
            print("Foo")
            firstTime = false
         } else {
            print("Bar")
        }
    }
test()
test()
```

Comment: Your variable in the scope of the function is reset everytime the function is calling itself.  Put it outside of the function, as a class variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am extracted `var firstTime = true` from function and its worked.

```
var firstTime = true
fun test(){
        if(firstTime){
            print("Foo")
            firstTime = false
         } else {
            print("Bar")
        }
    }
test()
test()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not an error, it's a warning. And it only applies to the line `if(firstTime)`. After that, you are changing the variable and that's working just fine. However, you're not using the variable after you change it (yet).